# Please review the image and comment

Tags: nikon, prime, 50mm

Hey fellow Photographers,

I've taken the below image today and info attached. Please review and comment on it which would help me to improve.

Exif :

Body : Nikon d5300
Lens : 50mm
Exposure : 1/400s
Aperture : f1.8
ISO : 100
No Flash

Photoshop Edits :

- Clarity been increased
- Adjusted whites/black/shadows

[image]

Comment: Please see http://meta.photo.stackexchange.com/questions/2039/can-we-re-open-the-door-to-something-a-little-like-photo-critique on critique questions on this site

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because open-ended critiques are specifically off-topic here.

Comment: @MichaelClark If i would have changed the question as 'How should i have taken this image to stand out', eligible for this forum??? If you are closing gate by saying not appropriate then should be guiding for correct door mate

Comment: @VinoM Please read the discussion at the link above in the first comment."How to make an image stand out" is still very non-specific and open ended. An appropriate question would be to state more specifically what you are trying to accomplish with the photo, what you have tried, and why you find the results unacceptable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As smow said, most answers will be subjective, but here are some thoughts -

Currently there are two main visual elements - the in-focus leaf at right, and the out-of-focus cluster of yellow dots at left. I think this draws the eye between the two. At some point though, we also notice that behind the right-hand leaf, is another leaf, similar, but out of focus. So now there is another line for the eye to follow, from main leaf to background leaf.

However, apart from moving my gaze around between these three elements, there is no obvious single subject or highlight. The in-focus leaf is clearly the main subject but I don't see anything super special about it that makes it worth being the main subject. Likewise, the contrast between it and the other two elements is not stunning or stark enough to warrant it being the main subject.

They're nice visual elements and there is a mixture of in-focus sharpness and background textures, but nothing to really make the image stand out.

However, when I teach workshops and the question always comes up - how to make something "better", or "good", I always ask: define "good".

"Good" means (to me) "fit for purpose". If your purpose was to practice some technical aspect, then you have probably succeeded and it's a good shot. If you were looking to create a Windows desktop background, I would argue that again you have probably succeeded - there is a nice balance of muted tones that would sit in the background well. If your purpose was to create a book cover where the left-hand-side is going to contain text over the image, or a slightly opaque panel of text, you've succeeded. If you're documenting a particular plant species artistically, you've succeeded. If you want an image that stops everyone in their tracks in amazement, perhaps not this time.

Finally, I find the very bottom tip of the leaf is too near the bottom edge of the image (and this is personal taste) - I would give more space between it and the end, and maybe move the leaf further left (that is, the left edge of the lead ends approx mid-frame. I would extend the image to the right so the left edge of the leaf ends in the left half of the frame, and not the centre point).

Comment: Seriously i haven't noticed the other two subjects in the image which is drawing user's eye. I should thank you for the time you have taken to review my image and will keep in my mind your points when i take my camera again..Thanks a lot...

Comment: Keeping mindful about the background of an image is a great habit! :)

Answer (score 0):

Difficult to say anything, because since technically the picture is fine, any opinion would be purely subjetive.

Personally I don't really like all-green all-saturated nature photos, so I think I would reduce green saturation and increase red to bring out the leafes in the foreground some more. But as I said..